# Day: p(rain)=0.2 Week p(rain on 2 days)=?

Tags: probability

If on any given day of the week there is a 0.2 chance of rain. What is the probability of it raining on exactly two days?
Day: p(rain)=0.2 Week p(rain on 2 days)=?

Answer (score 1):

$P(\text{raining on exactly two days}) = {7 \choose 2} P(\text{rain})^{2}P(\text{not rain})^{5} = {7 \choose 2}P(\text{rain})^{2}(1 - P(\text{rain}))^{5} = {7 \choose 2}(0.2)^{2}(0.8)^{5}$

Comment: This is correct now, *assuming* that whether it rains or not is independent from day to day.  In reality, this is a horrible assumption to make.  If it rains one day it is often much more likely to rain again the next day and if it is sunny one day it is usually much more likely to remain sunny again the next day.  Of course, without the assumption there is no way to approach the problem and it would be otherwise impossible to answer.

Comment: @JMoravitz a markov chain approach would be appropriate in that case.

Comment: @rubikscube09 It is not uncommon to use the example of rainy days for an illustrative introductory example of markov chains, however even that is not a true model of weather which is quite chaotic in nature and makes several simplifications and assumptions which are otherwise not appropriate.  It is at least a better model than assuming independence.